# How I can start to capture packets and saving it by command line using Wireshark

Tags: macos, networking, wireshark, osx-mavericks

Could you tell me how I can start to capture packets with specific interface by command line and saving it by command line using Wireshark? I would like to save it on my Desktop.

OS X 10.9.2

Wireshark 1.10.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tshark` utility is included with wireshark for this purpose.

```
tshark -i en1 -w ~/Desktop/packet_capture_file.cap
```

You can also start `tcpdump` from a command line, and then open the resulting `.pcap` file in Wireshark's GUI

```
sudo tcpdump -i en1 -s 0 -B 524288 -w ~/Desktop/packet_capture_file.pcap
```

Both of those commands will start a capture of the interface `en1` and write the output to `packet_capture_file.pcap` on your desktop.